# Check mark the box with the correct text JQUERY

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, indexing

```
<div class="posts">
**<input id="chkbox_0" type="checkbox" value="chck_0" name="list" style="float:left;height:95px; width:15px;">**
<div class="title box " onclick="thisimg(0,252250)">
<div class="click" style="float:right;">
Clicks
<br>
<div id="count_0"> 0 </div>
</div>
 <div style="float:left; width:100px; overflow:hidden; white-space: pre;">
 **potdFeed**
 <br>
7 Hs 51 Ms ago
</div>
</div>
```

This is a different issue I am have with basically the same HTML just a different object.  I was using the COUNT to check mark the corresponding box now I'm trying to use the text in the div.

I have tried

```
 var mainDiv = $("div:contains(potdfeed)");  
 ($(this.mainDiv).eq[3].css('color', 'red'));
```

and this

```
  $ (this).css('color', 'red');
   alert($(this).closest("click").find("posts").index(this));
  $('input:checkbox').prop(checkbox , true)
  });
```

You can view the website [ZYNGA POKER](http://www.zyngapokerchipsfree.com/?page=6)
You will notice some of the squared names are the same but the text isn't indexed like  the checkbox and I'm stumped on how to check the box of the certain text.   So let's say that there are 8 potdfeed on the page I just want those checked.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with `div:contains(potdfeed)`

1. It's missing quotes around potdfeed
2. Everything's case-sensitive, so it should be `potdFeed`
3. `div:contains()` will find any outer div that contains that content or that has children that contain that content. To only get the immediate div, either make your selector more exact (`.posts .title div`), or add a class to the name div.

That leaves you with something like this:

```
$(".posts .title div:contains('potdFeed')")`
```

That gets you the set of matching divs. To find the corresponding checkboxes, walk up the tree to the outer `.posts` div, and then find the contained `<input>` tag:

```
.closest('.posts').find('input')
```

So your final code looks something like this:

```
$(".posts .title div:contains('potdFeed')")
    .closest('.posts')
    .find('input')
    .prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: So I was looking at it totally wrong.  I was trying to invoke an instance of $("div:contains(potdfeed)") to try and index the checkbox but my syntax was wrong anyway so it would have never worked.  Jcsanyi your solution works perfectly!   Thank you for the quick response.